# How do I change background color of each list item with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xhtml

I'm struggling trying to change the background color of each item of a list when I move the mouse over it.

I have a list more or less like this:

```html
<ul id="ul_menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do it with Javascript as the following:

```html
var list = document.getElementByID("ul_menu");
 var listItems = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 function mouseOver() {
  for (li in listItems){
   li.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
 } 
 function mouseOut() {
  for (li in listItems){
   li.style.backgroundColor = null;
  }
 }
```

I'm generating this HTML code dynamically with XSLT from a XML file, so I'm unable to choose an specific ID for each list item.

Could you help me?

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you describe what the issue is with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly (please let me know if I'm not), you just want to change the background color of the text when the mouse pointer hovers over a list item, correct?

If so, you can do this really easily with a little CSS:

```css
.yellow:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" class="yellow">Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" class="yellow">Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" class="yellow">Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you really want to use JavaScript, it's still possible, but you'll need to specify the width of the highlighted area. Try something like this:

```js
function yellowa1(x) {
  a1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  a1.style.width = "5px";
}

function yellowb2(x) {
  b2.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  b2.style.width = "5px";
}

function yellowc3(x) {
  c3.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  c3.style.width = "5px";
}

function nulla1(x) {
  a1.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}

function nullb2(x) {
  b2.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}

function nullc3(x) {
  c3.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li onmouseover="yellowa1(this)" onmouseout="nulla1(this)" id="a1">a</li>
    <li onmouseover="yellowb2(this)" onmouseout="nullb2(this)" id="b2">b</li>
    <li onmouseover="yellowc3(this)" onmouseout="nullc3(this)" id="c3">c</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

---

Also, for future reference, be aware that an `id` is used to identify one element, whereas a `class` can be used to identify several. As well, Only the `I` in the `Id` part of the DOM method `.getElementById` should be capitalized, not both letters. And make sure that your `<ul>` element is defined.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your help. Yes, you are right, I was trying to do it with JS to reuse the function, but not sure if possible. Do you know if it's possible? Thanks.

Comment: It is definitely possible! I've edited my answer to include how you would go about this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #ul_menu li:hover{
     background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
//Try using just CSS to achieve the result if you don't mind
<ul id="ul_menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector" >Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector" >Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#ref" title="go to ref" id="menu_selector">Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```